# Error while starting RoboCode

Tags: c#, robocode

I am getting the following error while trying to run Robocode.bat

**error: could not find or load main class robocode.robocode**

I checked the java Installation, I checked it in the java website, the installation is fine.
I also added the path in environmental variable.
My OS is Windows 8

Also I am trying to install RoboCode for.Net

Comment: are you still having the problem?

Comment: @PhilippSander yes, I am having it again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the bat cannot find the robocode.jar

check if it is still in the lib folder of your installation. and you did not move the bat file

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Actually I haven't changed any location and the file is there in the folder. I have edited the question, I am installing robocode for .net. DO you think anything else has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow this instruction (i.e. install the java version of Robocode, then install the Robocode .NET plugin):

> .NET plug-in for Robocode must be installed *on top of* your *existing*
>   Robocode directory.

http://robowiki.net/wiki/Robocode/.NET/Create_a_.NET_robot_with_Visual_Studio#Prerequisites

[Old question I know, but I ran into this problem today and didn't see this answer here.]